# Get Django version from source project

Tags: django, version

How are you friends.
I have got one django source project and I would like to know what the version of this project is.
How to get django framework version from source project?
Cheers!

Comment: go in shell then type`import django django.VERSION` or in the console `./manage.py --version` is not working for you?

Comment: ofcourse I can get the current installed django version.
what I want is, to know with what version this project was developed?
For example, let's imagine you didn't install django yet and got source project. then how to know what version of django was this project built by?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you found any commented URL related django documentation in any django default file 'urls.py, settings.py, wsgi.py' that will show django version like I have wsgi.py of demo project that have comments

```
"""
WSGI config for demo project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""
```

Here 1.9 showing django version that was used to build this project.

This is the last option you can find django project version if not mention in django project requirements.txt file