# How To Find Django Version Of A Project?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a Django project forked from GitHub. But I don't know which version of Django is used in that project. How can I find the Django version of the project ? I haven't installed Django in my PC.

Comment: check requirements file(requirements.txt/requirements.pip)

Comment: There is no mention about django version in requirements.txt file

Comment: then check settings.py file, there could be a mention with which version of django generated that file

Comment: I checked. But not mentioned Django version in settings.py file

Comment: Please share the GitHub project link here

Comment: @Suhas_Pote https://github.com/chb/indivo_server/tree/v2.0.0

Comment: I found the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486129/get-django-version-from-source-project/44487731#44487731)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution on my own. In the top of the `settings.py` file, you can see an auto generated multiline comment like this

```py
"""
Django settings for remedy_server project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
```

In that comment, the Django version of your project has been mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You can check Django(installed) version with

```
pip show django
```

or

```
pip3 show django
```

In your case, it is difficult to find Django version since it is not mentioned in any file/s such as `requirements.txt`

You can assume the Django version used for existing GitHub project by `Latest commit on [Date]` by looking at that date you can assume figure out which version was used.

Note: You can check the logfile (if it is available)

Answer (score 0):

Django version or any other package version

Open the terminal or command prompt

Type

pip show django

Answer (score 0):

> > > import django

> > > print(django.get_version())

3.0.7